# Why are new JSP's throwing JasperException : Unable to compile class for JSP

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I have a tomcat 6 instance running multiple applications.

We migrated to a new server, with a different domain, and an SSL certificate.

Now, suddenly, the most basic .jsp no longer works.

I putty'ed into the server, went to the application folder and created a new file called test.jsp :

> cd /usr/tomcat/webapps/myDumbApplication
>
> vi test.jsp

test.jsp contains nothing special, only this  :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
TEST
</body>
</html>
```

However, when I open that newly created page in a browser, I see the following error : 
[image]

What the heck is going on, that I cannot create a new .jsp on the fly.

I also cannot make a change to a .jsp.  When I edited a file it broke and shows the same error.

Comment: Are you sure jsp file is not corrupted? Do you mean you cant open the file to edit it? can you be sure that there's no unwanted characters or lines in the file?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are using Java 8 version with Tomcat 6. You need to upgrade your Tomcat version (preferable to Tomcat 8)
Or try to change your JRE

Comment: How would that cause this problem?

Comment: New JDK above Java 7 is not supported by Tomcat 6.

Comment: To whoever down voted,  please advise on the reason.

Comment: Yes you are exactly right, 

The old server used Java 1.4 and Tomcat 6.

The new server uses Java 1.8 and Tomcat 6